# Formula on product family

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

Can any one help me on this .
I do have few of the products with different names in different product family.

If the product line for the product selected in opportunity items is  ‘DIE’  make following changes .
1) unit price should change to $.01.

Any suggestion plz.

Comment: You will have to write a trigger to do this as the unit price is a standard field and not a formula.

Comment: @Eric:Can u help me out with an example.Is Unit price same as List price.How are unit price ,sales price and list price related .

Comment: Everything you need about those fields is here: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

Answer (score 1):

Nikkey  -- normal practice with the OpportunityLineitem and PricebookEntry table is the following (assuming you have Products enabled which you do):

1. Each PricebookEntry row represents the list price of a given SKU (Product2) on a given pricebook for a given currency. This is contained in a field named `UnitPrice` (API name)
2. Each OpportunityLineItem refers to a specific PricebookEntry row (that is what the UI does when you pick a product for an Opportunity)
3. `OpportunityLineItem.Listprice` is equal to `OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntry.unitPrice`
4. The user can then enter the price of the Product as sold to the customer (or as expected to be sold once opportunity closes). This goes into `OpportunityLineItem.UnitPrice` (API name)

By way of example, if Product2: `00Foo` on Pricebook X has price of 10.00 USD, then when selected on the Opportunity as an OpportunityLineitem will have:

- OpportunityLineItem.ListPrice = 10.00 (this comes from the product catalog and is not editable)
- OpportunityLineItem.UnitPrice = 8.00 (this is user editable)

So, if what you are trying to do is default the OLI.Unitprice to 0.01 and you can't set up the PricebookEntry.UnitPrice (i.e. List price) to be 0.01, then you will need a trigger on OLI to do the defaulting - formulas won't work as OLI.Unitprice is a user entry field